# Is it better to have file stored as a zip in cloud service?

Tags: ios, cloud-computing, cloud

I am developing enterprise iPad application which contained large amount of different bundle data in terms of group of images.

Is it worth to stored as a compressed file format or normal set of individual files?

I am not worrying about huge amount of data which is reside in the cloud.

My concern is that cloud computing provider only charges depending upon the request not about how much data where stored.

If I store single file in cloud then it make more request while using the app. So it will cost so much.

Is it better to be stored as a compressed file in cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Given the power the IPad and other tablets have, I think that uncompressing one "big" file should not be a big deal in your program. Of course, what "big" means is totally subjective... And since your provider charges you per request, it's a smart thing to do.

It's also always a good thing to try to make as few requests to the cloud as possible regardless of the provider charging model, and the type of the application. You never know when a connection to the cloud could be cut off, right ?

Finally, it's also a good thing if you update your package after deploying your application. If you allow updates, your application would only need to check if **one file** has been updated.

Edit: kinda related: [one single compressed js file VS compressed requirejs module files](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/154931/32008)